How to use ? to convert to a newtype error variant of thiserror::Error
I can not figure out how to avoid needing to use 'map_err' to first map the external crate's error to my crate's enum Error.
At the moment I have this solution with a newtype, but I don't like having to call map_err everywhere. How can I fix this?
A playground with my current workaround, and a little comment on what I would like to write instead: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=15e5ee935fe801f64cbb082722f0775b.

I think you shouldn't need to manually implement e.g. Display for OtherError. As I understand it, the whole point of thiserror is to do such things for you.

I was making this way too difficult. Here's the simple solution: Implement From for Error:
impl From<ExternalError> for Error {
    fn from(e: ExternalError) -> Self {
        Error::Other(OtherError::new(e))
    }
}

